# class crashes on device not in simulator

Tags: iphone

I have a problem with my iPhone app in Xcode 4.2 for iOS 6.
My app is working and i have have a download button in het bottom bar. I you press this in the simulator it works fine and does his job. When i press the same button on the device with the same build of my app it crashes. I cant see any warnings in the console. But i have this crash report and the code of mine is below it. I have really no idea why this is not working on the device.

```
     OS Version:      iOS 6.0 (10A5338d)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x52574c53
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x387ec5b0 0x387e9000 + 13744
1   Foundation                      0x34cce0ba 0x34cc8000 + 24762
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3034e5f8 0x302ae000 + 656888
3   CoreFoundation                  0x302c2030 0x302ae000 + 81968
4   Foundation                      0x34ccdfde 0x34cc8000 + 24542
5   MusicTube                       0x0000d54a 0x1000 + 50506
6   MusicTube                       0x0000d67e 0x1000 + 50814
7   MusicTube                       0x0000bb86 0x1000 + 43910
8   UIKit                           0x313ab4d2 0x31394000 + 95442
9   UIKit                           0x31464f22 0x31394000 + 855842
10  UIKit                           0x313ab4d2 0x31394000 + 95442
11  UIKit                           0x313ab484 0x31394000 + 95364
12  UIKit                           0x313ab45e 0x31394000 + 95326
13  UIKit                           0x313ab1b4 0x31394000 + 94644
14  UIKit                           0x313abb32 0x31394000 + 97074
15  UIKit                           0x313a9f5a 0x31394000 + 89946
16  UIKit                           0x31398126 0x31394000 + 16678
17  UIKit                           0x31397a0a 0x31394000 + 14858
18  GraphicsServices                0x375335ec 0x3752d000 + 26092
19  GraphicsServices                0x3753321c 0x3752d000 + 25116
20  CoreFoundation                  0x3034167c 0x302ae000 + 603772
21  CoreFoundation                  0x30341620 0x302ae000 + 603680
22  CoreFoundation                  0x3034041a 0x302ae000 + 599066
23  CoreFoundation                  0x302bd7fe 0x302ae000 + 63486
24  CoreFoundation                  0x302bd68a 0x302ae000 + 63114
25  GraphicsServices                0x37532334 0x3752d000 + 21300
26  UIKit                           0x313be1f6 0x31394000 + 172534
27  MusicTube                       0x00013312 0x1000 + 74514
28  MusicTube                       0x00003250 0x1000 + 8784

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31975d24 0x31964000 + 72996
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666dd00 0x3665b000 + 77056
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666db46 0x3665b000 + 76614
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3665b9a4 0x3665b000 + 2468

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x319765e0 0x31964000 + 75232
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x348fb1fa 0x348f5000 + 25082
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x348faed8 0x348f5000 + 24280

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31975d24 0x31964000 + 72996
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666dd00 0x3665b000 + 77056
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666db46 0x3665b000 + 76614
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3665b9a4 0x3665b000 + 2468

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31975d24 0x31964000 + 72996
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666dd00 0x3665b000 + 77056
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666db46 0x3665b000 + 76614
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3665b9a4 0x3665b000 + 2468

Thread 5 name:  WebThread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x319750b0 0x31964000 + 69808
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x366700aa 0x3665b000 + 86186
2   WebCore                         0x35ac6336 0x35ac1000 + 21302
3   WebCore                         0x35ac6698 0x35ac1000 + 22168
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30341bd6 0x302ae000 + 605142
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3033fe42 0x302ae000 + 597570
6   CoreFoundation                  0x3034026e 0x302ae000 + 598638
7   CoreFoundation                  0x302bd7fe 0x302ae000 + 63486
8   CoreFoundation                  0x302bd68a 0x302ae000 + 63114
9   WebCore                         0x35b32d06 0x35ac1000 + 466182
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666bc36 0x3665b000 + 68662
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3665b9b0 0x3665b000 + 2480

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31964f64 0x31964000 + 3940
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31965142 0x31964000 + 4418
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3034154e 0x302ae000 + 603470
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30340224 0x302ae000 + 598564
4   CoreFoundation                  0x302bd7fe 0x302ae000 + 63486
5   CoreFoundation                  0x302bd68a 0x302ae000 + 63114
6   Foundation                      0x34cd951e 0x34cc8000 + 70942
7   Foundation                      0x34d727ee 0x34cc8000 + 698350
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666bc36 0x3665b000 + 68662
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3665b9b0 0x3665b000 + 2480

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31975d24 0x31964000 + 72996
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666dd00 0x3665b000 + 77056
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666db46 0x3665b000 + 76614
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3665b9a4 0x3665b000 + 2468

Thread 8 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31975040 0x31964000 + 69696
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666f608 0x3665b000 + 83464
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x366d1012 0x3665b000 + 483346
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x390662f6 0x3900b000 + 373494
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x391798e8 0x3900b000 + 1501416
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x3918bf9c 0x3900b000 + 1576860
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666bc36 0x3665b000 + 68662
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3665b9b0 0x3665b000 + 2480

Thread 9 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31975040 0x31964000 + 69696
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666f608 0x3665b000 + 83464
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x366d0fe2 0x3665b000 + 483298
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x3910d302 0x3900b000 + 1057538
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x3910d242 0x3900b000 + 1057346
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x3918bf9c 0x3900b000 + 1576860
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666bc36 0x3665b000 + 68662
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3665b9b0 0x3665b000 + 2480

Thread 10 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31964f64 0x31964000 + 3940
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31965142 0x31964000 + 4418
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3034154e 0x302ae000 + 603470
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30340224 0x302ae000 + 598564
4   CoreFoundation                  0x302bd7fe 0x302ae000 + 63486
5   CoreFoundation                  0x302bd68a 0x302ae000 + 63114
6   WebCore                         0x35b52088 0x35ac1000 + 594056
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x3918bf9c 0x3900b000 + 1576860
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666bc36 0x3665b000 + 68662
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3665b9b0 0x3665b000 + 2480

Thread 11 name:  WebCore: LocalStorage
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31975040 0x31964000 + 69696
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666f608 0x3665b000 + 83464
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x366d0fe2 0x3665b000 + 483298
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x390662c8 0x3900b000 + 373448
4   WebCore                         0x3620e4ce 0x35ac1000 + 7656654
5   WebCore                         0x3620e2d2 0x35ac1000 + 7656146
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x3918bf9c 0x3900b000 + 1576860
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666bc36 0x3665b000 + 68662
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3665b9b0 0x3665b000 + 2480

Thread 12 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31975548 0x31964000 + 70984
1   CoreFoundation                  0x303456e0 0x302ae000 + 620256
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666bc36 0x3665b000 + 68662
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3665b9b0 0x3665b000 + 2480

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31975d24 0x31964000 + 72996
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666dd00 0x3665b000 + 77056
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666db46 0x3665b000 + 76614
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3665b9a4 0x3665b000 + 2468

Thread 14 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31975040 0x31964000 + 69696
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666f608 0x3665b000 + 83464
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x366d0fe2 0x3665b000 + 483298
3   CoreMedia                       0x3074cf3a 0x30749000 + 16186
4   MediaToolbox                    0x34f9692c 0x34f92000 + 18732
5   CoreMedia                       0x30770d28 0x30749000 + 163112
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666bc36 0x3665b000 + 68662
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3665b9b0 0x3665b000 + 2480

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31975d24 0x31964000 + 72996
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666dd00 0x3665b000 + 77056
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3666db46 0x3665b000 + 76614
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3665b9a4 0x3665b000 + 2468

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x3ace9b54    r1: 0x35306320      r2: 0x303d8bd0      r3: 0xffffffff
    r4: 0x52574c4b    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x303d8bd0      r7: 0x2fdfd5c8
    r8: 0x2fdfdbdc    r9: 0x0d4c18c8     r10: 0x2fdfd6c4     r11: 0x004468b0
    ip: 0x3a4af6f8    sp: 0x2fdfd5b4      lr: 0x34cce0c1      pc: 0x387ec5b0
  cpsr: 0x20070030

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x93fff +MusicTube armv7  <ca75c5c085683a9ea3236afc5eaf836e> /var/mobile/Applications/4282E492-9720-4333-ADCC-681C0B2FE6CF/MusicTube.app/MusicTube
0x2fed0000 - 0x2fef0fff  dyld armv7  <d7b9e4bc402f3645b9273bb202cdce5b> /usr/lib/dyld
0x302ae000 - 0x303defff  CoreFoundation armv7  <4ad30769f9aa301a9157428dec03a3dd> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x303df000 - 0x303f2fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <784fa6dc68b13e44b9b970954081ac8e> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x30402000 - 0x30407fff  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib armv7  <3244792c47e034c292cf30f92fae6415> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUSupport.framework/libGPUSupportMercury.dylib
0x30444000 - 0x30445fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <38160b3c19643564a6b0e59da62e0b4f> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x30446000 - 0x30462fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <18abea0052573ae09f79c794c427c4b1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x304d1000 - 0x304d6fff  Marco armv7  <db14228e2c0b3950ba3fcf3cea3f0db9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x304f4000 - 0x30504fff  Accounts armv7  <8e485280e65a379589e3ab6efdb64662> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x30737000 - 0x30748fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <85374d8eea603f5e8ec2f2f781195b14> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x30749000 - 0x307f3fff  CoreMedia armv7  <04ca5e9301bf30b587c3914fdd3297cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x308bf000 - 0x308d2fff  DataDetectorsUI armv7  <947d3af81d0c3196a4aa6b0b2bee0286> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x308d3000 - 0x30b88fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <cd0afaa5d938333eb2503c2aa7d7e3a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x30b89000 - 0x30c36fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <7b824bb27f413d2ab1b3af9dbc5022fd> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x30d90000 - 0x30e44fff  CoreImage armv7  <1ab1bb1d30453d9c9bed231d23d30212> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x30f6c000 - 0x30fa6fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <9ae41e8cec1d3c4e8a09c43f83212369> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x30fa7000 - 0x30fbffff  EAP8021X armv7  <f39f04d92a973e1cb4688554b5b42262> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x30fc0000 - 0x30fc7fff  MobileIcons armv7  <96ada0b2450f371c890c751a4688a9e5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x31028000 - 0x311fefff  ImageIO armv7  <1ea0cf77b7003199b14d57557cc8952f> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x31368000 - 0x31388fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <334026b61da23d92aefe0df7d3155935> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x31394000 - 0x318c5fff  UIKit armv7  <dd048816d3af3d64b86a549312304690> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x318c6000 - 0x318cbfff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <c030a190a5ce33d187a875910f86f352> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x31962000 - 0x31963fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <463060b8044a3f66932432d98afa0497> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x31964000 - 0x3197afff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <eff667260cfc374691ad67ab35205e8a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x31a46000 - 0x31a49fff  MobileSystemServices armv7  <0fd5382615e9366d97942c16ebf47b3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x31ab0000 - 0x31b21fff  GameKitServices armv7  <930fdaa9d16a3e6db8101246472c3a6d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/GameKitServices
0x31b4c000 - 0x31cf2fff  CoreData armv7  <5f6308d43f103850a05cf28b96f66e0b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x31d4a000 - 0x31d4cfff  TCC armv7  <f268be00645f3170b0a5a06d2a77156b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x31d4d000 - 0x31d4ffff  MessageSupport armv7  <9188a2a529e035cc88c200aea45f151b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessageSupport.framework/MessageSupport
0x3201d000 - 0x3207efff  AddressBook armv7  <acaf0922af2b39718de5de6ee535ff18> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x320e5000 - 0x320eefff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <540f37f13ee739aca989c84469e8cc87> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x320ef000 - 0x320f1fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <4375a2def6b331c7a152faeef9658318> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x3210d000 - 0x3210dfff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <08ba5c97c9413e16b336c7e5ccfc7edf> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3210e000 - 0x3210efff  LegacyHandle armv7  <985a58f3a0923546a825a6c899955aa6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/Frameworks/LegacyHandle.framework/LegacyHandle
0x32144000 - 0x3214cfff  XPCObjects armv7  <719dac9cf6073f4a9a0e3bb662eb4601> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x3214f000 - 0x32169fff  ICE armv7  <b22eb8a170e334d0bb946dcdb383e279> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/Frameworks/ICE.framework/ICE
0x32185000 - 0x32187fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b0138f0a044636029479a12709942ee9> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x32260000 - 0x32276fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <d25b0355b59131cbbd248a2e9f1e63b1> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x3229b000 - 0x322b0fff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <97ea074dabc03708a2129c7f95415be8> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x322b1000 - 0x322b6fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <0830a7f70cfe315981e1f7f18da92250> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x322b7000 - 0x322b7fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <d9dd15a5f9bd34b390c2b5c2fe0cef75> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x322b8000 - 0x32313fff  CoreAudio armv7  <cd166a98944232439821716615c46084> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x32314000 - 0x3231bfff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <e436520914613108901f3e97f795888f> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x32321000 - 0x3232cfff  AccountSettings armv7  <d01d04bb6e463edca358926279e045df> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x3232d000 - 0x32333fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <6a0e7df489c93e658ff721f4d0936830> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x323ae000 - 0x323e9fff  AppSupport armv7  <70ca3d7feed837749369e731f48cd76f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x323ea000 - 0x3246ffff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <4cc671204eba384fbc95078f591653b3> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3247f000 - 0x32486fff  libsystem_notify.dylib armv7  <340bd67f3cde3180a7381477e23d00f6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x32589000 - 0x3258afff  DataMigration armv7  <05f2355f556a3a15b0a585570ed7dd10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x3258b000 - 0x32667fff  WebKit armv7  <8313503ad8fc33d4939878ad9bb04933> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x32a8f000 - 0x32a9cfff  ExternalAccessory armv7  <57f9ab7f369731b893ce2446eed28825> /System/Library/Frameworks/ExternalAccessory.framework/ExternalAccessory
0x32a9d000 - 0x32aaafff  ViceroyTrace armv7  <3b746210ec423f41985dc8fa3332bb86> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/Frameworks/ViceroyTrace.framework/ViceroyTrace
0x32aab000 - 0x32aaffff  IOSurface armv7  <c83b1d9390763180a40ff7b7b3d9ae96> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x32bcd000 - 0x32cd6fff  IMGSGX543GLDriver armv7  <4c8385245e5e33a28ff6fd141a2c1d81> /System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX543GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX543GLDriver
0x32cf0000 - 0x32db3fff  CFNetwork armv7  <6320d69fb5f3380495c17df1ad3d841a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x32db4000 - 0x32e14fff  CoreText armv7  <3575b536a6913020ac6196bac69358d7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x32e1b000 - 0x32e32fff  BackBoardServices armv7  <2ad8b45f0c17313db055696c5e9ccc88> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x32e4d000 - 0x32ec8fff  HomeSharing armv7  <b58412ff72913758a1318e57ee06e764> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x32ed2000 - 0x32ed8fff  BluetoothManager armv7  <6dcf77969a583894b5d4d1e0a88fe646> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager
0x33092000 - 0x33094fff  OAuth armv7  <f000496cc0963e8a834f846f87ec8518> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x330ae000 - 0x330b4fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <adf7ce0d8e5137408aa693be43476068> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x331ee000 - 0x33209fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <81ad7b74aca23cf8b11fabaeefa4fe4b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x33258000 - 0x332a2fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <5b9453f4d1573c7783806690d4477572> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x332a3000 - 0x332a5fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <42f6d5bb05b7357fa5f6aa642b9f5924> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x332a6000 - 0x333e5fff  vImage armv7  <4fec5d5386483ff9842f3bd846b64c5e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x333e6000 - 0x33423fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <06c2c3c54f6c394db2fee2e6e6f0767b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x33438000 - 0x33480fff  IOKit armv7  <85a617f1e07f3b90ade1b2242f65d631> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x33481000 - 0x33484fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <33c2fb9e67f539fea34af006450316c4> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x33485000 - 0x335bcfff  CoreGraphics armv7  <fdbaa340412b395095c8f286d4684b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x335bd000 - 0x336e2fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <19eac922a76c38ffa3050a2bf049bc50> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x336e3000 - 0x3372efff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <bded282eb5b03084b5e4ce32cf12a543> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3372f000 - 0x33736fff  SimpleKeyExchange armv7  <8a72bd8fe3333920bda1c799cbc45545> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/Frameworks/SimpleKeyExchange.framework/SimpleKeyExchange
0x337a8000 - 0x337abfff  libcache.dylib armv7  <a3d5fcc87c6532b78cdad77e6b8e42a0> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x33810000 - 0x33819fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <56b2960008c4374b8061318537feecdc> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x33824000 - 0x33838fff  QuickTime Plugin armv7  <a37bd4c4a26135d2a86422ce3ea5a93f> /System/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.webplugin/QuickTime Plugin
0x338ef000 - 0x3392dfff  FTServices armv7  <256ef4f8868234daa096d9d5c5f60885> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x3393f000 - 0x339c3fff  CoreMotion armv7  <691d1e9c76793d90a9ba3c55cf9b4c7a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x33b2d000 - 0x33c0bfff  GeoServices armv7  <eb59528424cf378db229ffab6f84eebd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x33c1e000 - 0x33c75fff  CoreLocation armv7  <f751994a0003369094655d5a0cd034fd> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x33c76000 - 0x33c8dfff  DictionaryServices armv7  <441a6e90d20e390bbe97cda0210bff95> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x33ccd000 - 0x33e0efff  MusicLibrary armv7  <3d53487b66c531b7a14342d98377f928> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x33e0f000 - 0x33e10fff  CoreSurface armv7  <1b5a6405204a353f84c47229f67ed821> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x343aa000 - 0x343aafff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <47d229f23d7d3bfb85255b8b5bd060d9> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x3448f000 - 0x344e1fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <dc6226e84f47398fbad71eaf5f8a279c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x344e2000 - 0x345cefff  VideoProcessing armv7  <6fb05fd13a8f335f98f31296e9ae204a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoProcessing.framework/VideoProcessing
0x345d3000 - 0x34601fff  Security armv7  <7003574db767355dbba2f94c068ad80e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x34602000 - 0x34602fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <dbcfd2ac7c353d23b5e0739673e64dda> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x3461b000 - 0x34628fff  TelephonyUtilities armv7  <3f91a39c06df38b28a669734e352ba88> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
0x34676000 - 0x3468bfff  libmis.dylib armv7  <9dee2ef2cf6535859de820ac85c83c34> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x3468c000 - 0x346a8fff  libsystem_m.dylib armv7  <0d0a1f0223d8344fb20a272398867db1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x346a9000 - 0x346dbfff  MobileAsset armv7  <b65a6e27c7383104a37ea9551ae37859> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x346e0000 - 0x346e1fff  IOAccelerator armv7  <59eec0834b4736bc8c9e8ba06029b38b>
```

My code to activate the class in the IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)download 
{
    DownloadInfo *dinfo=[self trySetUpDownload];
    if ([[dinfo FileTitle] length] >0 && [[dinfo FileUrl] length] >0)
    {
        [downloadButton setEnabled:NO];
        dinfo.delegate = self;
        [dinfo setUp:YES];
        [toolbar addSubview:dinfo.bar];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have experienced this phenomenon many times while developing on the iOS Simulator and testing on an iOS device. So much so that now I only develop on an iPhone, iPad, or iPod Touch.

Comment: Hard to say without stack symbols or an exception message, but I'll guess that it's a memory management problem since the so-called "address" it's trying to access looks suspiciously like a character string.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by adding NSLog statements to your download method to check and see if dinfo is nil or not.  Then, I'd make sure that downloadButton and toolbar are also valid:

```
NSLog(@"downloadButton: %@", [downloadButton description])
```

Comment: Yes this works properly. I thinks its deeper in the classes the button activates. But i cant past my code here on Stackoverflow. To many characters.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are retaining the object in  trySetUpDownload method.

if its not autorelease object may be you can try

DownloadInfo *dinfo=[[self trySetUpDownload] retain];  that might help you..